# How set dd(dump and die) in yii2 framework?

Tags: yii2, dump, dd, die

I want use DD (dump and die) like Laravel framework

How use it in yii2 framework?

Comment: Just add https://github.com/symfony/var-dumper package to your project via composer

Comment: Yii2 also has VarDumper. https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-helpers-vardumper

Comment: Create new file, create dd function, inlcude file in index.php.

Answer (score 0):

In yii2 create common component and add below code in component

```
if (function_exists('dd')) {
function dd(...$data)
{
    foreach ($data as $value) {
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($value);
        echo '</pre>';
        echo '<br>';
    }
    exit;
}
```

}

you can call above function in any where just use component.